# SVG jumps when try to move it

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add zoom and drag behavior to svg, the zoom is ok although I think it can be better but my problem is with dragging the svg, it immediately jumps and disappears as you can see in this  [**JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohdasalah/5swfrrdb/5/)

The code looks like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.attr("width", "100%")
   .attr("height", "100%")
   .attr('viewBox', '0 0 1200 1200')
   .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
   .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
  }))
  .append("g");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying your transform directly to the `svg` element.  You instead want to wrap your image it in a `g` and apply the transform to that:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.select("g");

svg.attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 1200 1200').attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet").call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
  }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8 text-left" id="vis" width="100%" height="100%">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve"> 
  <g>
  <image id="image0" width="1200" height="1200" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAASwCAQAAABBKHtEAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAJiS0dE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" />
</g>
</svg>

</div>
```